# Using eSprite for moving elements on TFT

Tags: c++, esp32

I start using [TFT_eSPI](https://github.com/Bodmer/TFT_eSPI) for one of my ESP32 project.
I don't have quite an experience with this library but wish to use draw several elements (like filled circles) floating/moving on the background image (without messing the background)
I tried to use TFT_eSprite as the foreground and push them, but noticed it leaves a trace on the background.

```
TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();
TFT_eSprite img = TFT_eSprite(&tft);

void drawCirle(int x, int y)
{
  img.setColorDepth(8);
  img.createSprite(36, 36);
  img.fillSprite(TFT_TRANSPARENT);
  img.fillCircle(18, 18, 8, TFT_BLUE);
  img.pushSprite(x, y, TFT_TRANSPARENT);
  img.deleteSprite();
}

int y, x = 8;
void setup()
{
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(0);

  tft.fillScreen(TFT_RED); // let say that's the background
}

void loop()
{
  drawCirle(x, y++); // this is forground

  if (y > 240)
  {
    y = 0;
    x += 16;
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to constantly rewrite the screen with your desired background, at the end of each loop iteration.

```
void loop()
{
  drawCirle(x, y++); // this is forground

  if (y > 240)
  {
    y = 0;
    x += 16;
  }
  delay(100); 
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_RED);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have kept the Sprite as a global variable, you could write another function that basically just fills the sprite area with background color after the delay and then finish the loop to create the next Sprite in the next location.

```
TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();
TFT_eSprite img = TFT_eSprite(&tft);

void drawCirle(int x, int y) {
  img.setColorDepth(8);
  img.createSprite(36, 36);
  img.fillSprite(TFT_TRANSPARENT);
  img.fillCircle(18, 18, 8, TFT_BLUE);
  img.pushSprite(x, y, TFT_TRANSPARENT);
}

void RemoveCircle(int x, int y) {
  img.fillScreen(TFT_RED);
  img.pushSprite(x, y, TFT_TRANSPARENT);
  img.deleteSprite();
}

int y, x = 8;
void setup() {
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_RED); // let say that's the background
}

void loop() {
  drawCirle(x, y++); // this is forground
  delay(100);
  RemoveCircle(x, y++); //Fill Sprite with BG color and delete it

  if (y > 240) {
    y = 0;
    x += 16;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modifide the fill sprite transparent to red and it works for me`

```
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>  // Hardware-specific library
// #include <TFT_eFEX.h>
TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();
TFT_eSprite img = TFT_eSprite(&tft);

void drawCirle(int x, int y)
{
  img.setColorDepth(8);
  img.createSprite(36, 36);
  img.fillSprite(TFT_RED);
  img.fillCircle(18, 18, 8, TFT_RED);
  img.fillCircle(18, 18, 8, TFT_BLUE);
  img.pushSprite(x, y, TFT_TRANSPARENT);
  img.deleteSprite();
}

int y, x = 8;
void setup()
{
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(0);

  tft.fillScreen(TFT_RED); // let say that's the background
}

void loop()
{
  drawCirle(x, y++); // this is forground

  if (y > 240)
  {
    y = 0;
    x += 16;
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

`